# Object Required Runtime error 424 . Using Vlookup to populate textbox in userform

Tags: vba, excel

I have a multipage userform called UserForm2. I am taking a 10 digit input from user in a textbox called txtmobno (short for mobile number) and then intend to use that input as an argument of vlookup function to get firstname from a worksheet called MD. Once, I have the first name as returned by vlookup, I want to populate textbox called txtfirstnm on UserForm2 with this firstname. The textbox should populate on clicking a command button called cmdcheck. But I am getting an error "Object Required". My code looks like this. What am I missing ? Thanks in advance

```
Private Sub cmdcheck_Click()

Me.txtfirstnm = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.txtmobno, MD.Range("a1:i10"), 2, 0)

End Sub
```

Comment: `MD` is undefined unless you've gone and made it some kind of public or private var.

Comment: Yes Jeeped. Many thanks ! Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

`MD` is undefined unless you've gone and made it some kind of public or private var. From your narrative this may be `Worksheets("MD")`.

```
Private Sub cmdcheck_Click()

    Me.txtfirstnm = Application.VLookup(Me.txtmobno, Worksheets("MD").Range("a1:i10"), 2, 0)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

so I figured that even if you rename the sheets in vba you use Sheet1 Sheet 2 and so on ... so replacing MD with Sheet1 worked !

Comment: See how a Worksheet [.CodeName property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837552.aspx) differs from a Worksheet [.Name property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196974.aspx).